# django redirected view not rendering

Tags: django, django-views

I defined the following views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from .models import LoadedData


def loaded_data(request):
    return HttpResponse("File successfully uploaded")

def collect_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = LoadedData(data=request.FILES['file'])
            instance.save()
            return redirect('loaded_data')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'pages/app_load_data.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the urls.py for the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.collect_data, name='collect_data'),
    path('loaded_data/', views.loaded_data, name='loaded_data')
]
```

This is the result of `python manage.py runserver` when I upload a file

```
[18/Jun/2018 17:46:45] "POST /app/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Jun/2018 17:46:45] "GET /app/loaded_data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26
```

But loaded_data isn't rendering anything, the app is stuck on the same page.

Comment: Did you turn redirects off in your browser?

Comment: Wat if you use `loaded_data` (without quotes) in the `redirect(..)`? What are your `urls.py`?

Comment: [edit] the question.

Comment: I tried, without success

Comment: well the page *is* fetched. It even transmits the 26 bytes, what happens if you "view source" in your web browser.

Comment: The source is that of ``pages/app_load_data.html``